# illegal_argument_exception: no mapping found for field

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to follow some tutorials on how to use elastic search (`version 12.1.0`) as search engine. And now, I'm trying to run these few lines:

```
function initMapping() {
    return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
        index: indexName,
        type: "document",
        body: {
            properties: {
                title: { type: "string" },
                content: { type: "string" },
                suggest: {
                    type: "completion",
                    analyzer: "simple",
                    search_analyzer: "simple",
                    payloads: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function addDocument(document) {
    return elasticClient.index({
        index: indexName,
        type: "document",
        body: {
            title: document.title,
            content: document.content,
            suggest: {
                input: document.title.split(" "),
                output: document.title,
                payload: document.metadata || {}
            }
        }
    });
}

function getSuggestions(input) {
    return elasticClient.suggest({
        index: indexName,
        body: {
            docsuggest: {
                text: input,
                completion: {
                    field: "suggest",
                    fuzzy: true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

But when I hit the related URL, I get these few lines as output:

```
{ [Error: [illegal_argument_exception] no mapping found for field [suggest]]   status: 400,   displayName: 'BadRequest',   message: '[illegal_argument_exception] no mapping found for field [suggest]',   path: '/docs-engine/_suggest',   query: {},   body:     { error: 
      { root_cause: [Object],
        type: 'search_phase_execution_exception',
        reason: 'all shards failed',
        phase: 'query',
        grouped: true,
        failed_shards: [Object],
        caused_by: [Object] },
     status: 400 },   statusCode: 400,   response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [suggest]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"docs-engine","node":"gxmLpCqdSISUvPh6fn56CQ","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [suggest]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [suggest]"}},"status":400}',   toString: [Function],   toJSON: [Function] }
```

So, the error says that elastic search cannot figure out the field `suggest`. I've tried to map other properties, but it wasn't possible to make. I always get the same error with the corresponding attribute.

Any brilliant idea please ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I don't have an answer for you, but if you use the code formatting for the output it will look better

Comment: having the same issue. i'm using elasticsearch 5 and the docs presents different query...