# illegal_argument_exception request contains unrecognized parameter: [mapping] - ElasticSearch Index Creation

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm, promise, elasticsearch-plugin

I have been using elasticsearch for the first time since yesterday and I am struggling to get simple functionalities up and running after two days working on it in reason of my limited knowledge.

My main goal is to accomplish a crud with Node.js + ElasticSearch. Now I am stuck to create an index by using `mapping` feature.

My straight question is: what I have to do in order to make this code works?

```
return client.indices.create({
    index: 'index_created_with_map',
    mapping: {
        posts: {
            user: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            post_date: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            message: {
                type: 'string'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestion what to check will be appreciated.

Plus that, although not part of my main question, any comment how to return properly the get and search function to `response.send(JSON.stringify(the data from elasticsearch))` and how to map `post_date` to date type instead of string  will be appreciated as I am stuck on it as well.

Bellow is all I have tried so far. I can see throw "Chrome ElastiSearch ToolBox extension" when I try without `mapping` feature like in `addToIndex` below it does work but I would like to have separate functions, one for create the index which I will run just once obviously and another for creating the "record" which will be part of my crud.

PS. I found very similar question here without any answer

[illegal_argument_exception: no mapping found for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962862/illegal-argument-exception-no-mapping-found-for-field)

error log:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/index_created_with_map] contains unrecognized parameter: [mapping]
    at respond (/home/demetrio/dev/WSs/NodeJs/greencard-dmz-es-oracle/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:289:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/demetrio/dev/WSs/NodeJs/greencard-dmz-es-oracle/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:248:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/demetrio/dev/WSs/NodeJs/greencard-dmz-es-oracle/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:164:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/demetrio/dev/WSs/NodeJs/greencard-dmz-es-oracle/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

My controller NodeJs

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

exports.teste = function (req, res) {

    var log = console.log.bind(console);

    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
    });

    function createIndexWithMapping() {
        return client.indices.create({
            index: 'index_created_with_map',
            mapping: {
                posts: {
                    user: {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    post_date: {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    message: {
                        type: 'string'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function createIndexWithoutMapping() {
        return client.create({
            index: 'index_created_without_map',
            type: 'posts',
            id: '1',
            body: {
                user: 'me',
                post_date: new Date(),
                message: 'Hello World!'
            },
            refresh: true
        });
    }

    function addToIndex() {
        return client.index({
            index: 'index_created_...according to the test',
            type: 'posts',
            id: '1',
            body: {
                user: 'me2',
                post_date: new Date(),
                message: 'Hello World!2'
            },
            refresh: true
        });
    }

    function search() {
        return client.search({
            index: 'index_created_...according to the test',
            type: 'posts',
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: {
                        body: 'Hello'
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(log);
    }

    function getFromIndex() {
        return client.get({
            index: 'index_created_...according to the test',
            type: 'posts',
            id: 1
        }).then(log);
    }


    function closeConnection() {
        client.close();
    }

    Promise.resolve()
        .then(createIndexWithMapping)
        //.then(createIndexWithoutMapping)
        //      .then(addToIndex)
        //    .then(search)
        //  .then(getFromIndex)
        .then(closeConnection);

    return res.send("a");

};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-first-elasticsearch-app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.0.2",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^12.1.3",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.6.1",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.8",
    "node-rest-client": "^2.5.0",
    "oauth2orize": "^1.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-http": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "reqclient": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve().then(createIndexWithMapping) .... ` looks wrong. What do you think you are achieving with that code?

Comment: Did you try to put the "mappings" property needs to be inside the "body" property as suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25456701/2848895

Comment: Jaromanda, I understand I am creating the index. It is my first time using ELasticSearch. As a simple analogy, "I want to create the empty database". PS. I know database isn't the correct term in ElasticSearch but you probably can understand what I want to do with this comment. In https://gist.github.com/StephanHoyer/b9cd6cbc4cc93cee8ea6  you can see similar idea: "... client.indices.create({
    index: 'test',
    mapping: {
      house: {
        name: {
type: 'string'...

Comment: @DemeCarvO, kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1):

According to [elasticsearch.js » 5.5 API Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-5-5.html)

> **client.indices.create([params, [callback]])**
>
> **Params**
>
> - body
>
> Object, JSON — An optional request body, as either JSON or a JSON serializable object. See the elasticsearch docs for details about what can be specified here.

And According to the [API Convension doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-conventions.html)

> **Generic Parameters**
>
> - body
>
> String, Anything — The body to send along with this request. If the body is a string it will be passed along as is, otherwise it is passed to the serializer and converted to either JSON or a newline separated list of JSON objects based on the API method.

So you should send `mapping` property as a request body inside the `body` property

**A working example:**

```
const es = require('elasticsearch');

const elasticsearchClient = new es.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace',
});

elasticsearchClient.indices.create({
    index: `index_created_with_map`,
    body: {
        mappings: {
            type_name: {
                // ...
            },
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic Parameters

body

Anything — The body to send along with this request. If the body is a string it will be passed along as is, otherwise, it is passed to the serializer and converted to either JSON or a newline separated list of JSON objects based on the API method.

**Don't forget to add "body" before declaring "mappings"**

**Example:**

```
    function createIndices() {
        return client.indices.create({
          index: "indicesName",
          body: {
            mappings: {
              text: {
                properties: {
                  id: {
                    type: "integer"
                  },
                  label: {
                    type: "keyword"
                  },
                  state: {
                    type: "keyword"
                  },
                  startTime: {
                    type: "date",
                    format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
                  },
                  updateTime: {
                    type: "date",
                    format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

**Output:**

```
  {
      "acknowledged": true,
      "shards_acknowledged": true,
      "index": "indicesName"
  }
```